# BLE broadcaster device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I would like my BLE device (running on Linux) to be a broadcaster (broadcast data) - no connection is to be allowed. Following are the questions I have:

1. Which BLE profile would be most suitable for this requirement?
2. I understand that GATT is mandatory - does it mean I should use GATT and advertise my data in beacon and disallow any connection?
3. I have seen that Windows doesn't scan a BLE device which is simply a broadcaster i.e doesn't allow connection. Why so and what should I do for Windows to detect my broadcaster device?

Regards

Comment: While it is no longer supported, you should look at the existing Eddystone standard to guide your design and show what's possible. https://github.com/google/eddystone

Comment: If in the future, I would like to allow connection, then EddyStone won't be suitable right. So will it be ok, if I configure broadcaster (GAP role) and enable GATT server on my BLE device but disallow connection for now? So in the future, I will have to just allow connection on the GATT server side and still get it to work?

Comment: You can do both. Eddystone, for example, has a GATT service (Eddystone Configuration) that can be advertised when connectable. https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/configuration-service  You don't need to constrain yourself to Eddystone; it's not an ongoing standard. The real point is that it's a good starting point that has known characteristics and has already been implemented and tested for many platform and situations. But you should feel free to change it at will to fit your needs.

Comment: You can do both means - i can use Eddystone for broadcasting and connection or  choose to use GATT server and allow connection and mention custom information in beacon? Is that what you meant?

Comment: I mean that the Eddystone spec includes a GATT service. But that's equivalent to what you've said. (You can broadcast in a way compatible with Eddystone, and you can also use Eddystone's configuration service, or any other service you'd like to design, to communicate over GATT. It's also easiest to think of Eddystone's broadcast service as just being GATT advertising; this will make it easier if you want to port this to iOS.)